# How can I prepend and append to each member of an array?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, array

I have an array:

```
CATEGORIES=(one two three four)
```

I can prepend to each array member using parameter expansion:

```
echo ${CATEGORIES[@]/#/foo }
```

I can append to each array member the same way:

```
echo ${CATEGORIES[@]/%/ bar}
```

How can I do both? None of these work:

```
echo ${CATEGORIES[@]/(.*)/foo \1 bar}
echo ${CATEGORIES[@]/(.*)/foo $1 bar}
echo ${CATEGORIES[@]/(.*)/foo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} bar}
```

Comment: Related: [Does bash support back references in parameter expansion?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/361134)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what your ultimate aim is, you could use `printf`:

```
$ a=(1 2 3)
$ printf "foo %s bar\n" "${a[@]}"
foo 1 bar
foo 2 bar
foo 3 bar
```

`printf` re-uses the format string until all the arguments are used up, so it provides an easy way to apply some formatting to a set of strings.

Comment: This works for my purposes, although it would be nice to have a pure bash solution.

Comment: @Koveras `bash -c 'help printf'`.

Comment: Oh, so it is pure bash :)

Comment: Note that if you pass an empty array this results in `foo  bar` instead of an empty string, which might be unexpected.

Answer (score 10):

For the record, with `zsh`, there's the `${^array}` operator that turns on brace-like expansion on the elements of the array. So:

```
$ a=(one two three)
$ b=('foo '${^a}' bar')
$ printf '<%s>\n' $b
<foo one bar>
<foo two bar>
<foo three bar>
```

Search and replace also works in `zsh`.

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' ${a//(#m)*/foo $MATCH bar}
<foo one bar>
<foo two bar>
<foo three bar>
```

As well as `printf -v` on an array:

```
$ b=(); printf -v b 'foo %s bar' "$a[@]"
$ printf '<%s>\n' $b
<foo one bar>
<foo two bar>
<foo three bar>
```

Your `echo ${CATEGORIES[@]/(.*)/foo \1 bar}` would work in `ksh93` if written as:

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${CATEGORIES[@]/@(.*)/foo \1 bar}"
<foo one bar>
<foo two bar>
<foo three bar>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
p='* "foo  '
s='  bar $USER' 
CATEGORIES=(one two three four)
CATEGORIES=("${CATEGORIES[@]/#/$p}")
CATEGORIES=("${CATEGORIES[@]/%/$s}")

paste <(printf '[%s]\n' "${!CATEGORIES[@]}") \
      <(printf '%s\n'    "${CATEGORIES[@]}")
```

Output:

```
[0] * "foo  one  bar $USER
[1] * "foo  two  bar $USER
[2] * "foo  three  bar $USER
[3] * "foo  four  bar $USER
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *special case* solution which is suitable when the appended (or prepended) string is a *single character*, and you don't need the values in a new array:

```
array=( aa bb cc )
IFS="]"                        # or, IFS="["
echo "${array[*]/#/ [}$IFS"    # or, echo "$IFS${array[*]/%/] }
```

which produces output `[aa] [bb] [cc]`.

- quoted form `"${array[*]}"` adds separator `]` between each pair (the first character of `IFS`, this is where the constraints arise)
- `${array[*]/#/ [}` prepends  `[` to each element (or `/%/` form to append)
- finally add a trailing `]` (from `IFS`) to the expanded value

If these steps are applied one by one you would get:

```
aa]bb]cc
 [aa] [bb] [cc
 [aa] [bb] [cc]
```

(You could also trivially recover the data as a new array *if* the values contain no whitespace.)

You can do the distinct prefix/postfix operations in a one-liner:

```
for ii in "${array[@]/#/foo }"; do echo "${ii/%/ bar}"; done
```

This is a more robust `printf` solution that copies to a new array:

```
mapfile -d '' newarray < <(printf "foo %s bar\0" "${array[@]}")
```

albeit at the expense of a subshell (bash-4.4 required for `mapfile -d`)

Finally a loop variation that copies to a new array, and also handles sparse and associative arrays, if needed.

```
declare -a array newarray   # -a for indexed array, -A for associative
array=( one two three )
for ii in "${!array[@]}"; do
  printf -v "newarray[$ii]" "foo %s bar" "${array[$ii]}"
done
```

(`printf` is not required, you could assign directly, but it's clearer IMHO. `bash` doesn't (yet!) support printing into an array, but `zsh` does, giving you a loop free copy and transform one-liner, see Stéphane's answer above.)

---

What would be useful here is if `bash` supported the common `&` (like `$MATCH` in `zsh`) as a place-holder for the matched string in expansions. *The code is there* (and has been for a long time), but sadly it's not yet enabled (see `shouldexp_replacement()` in [`subst.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c?h=bash-4.4#n7407)). If you enable it (two `#if 0` changes, and recompile), this works as hoped:

```
array=( aa bb cc )
newarray=( "${array[@]/*/foo & bar}" )
```

No matter, perhaps available in the next version...

`compgen` has a prefix/suffix operation (and supports `&`, but not in a way we can use here). The best we can do with it isn't as good a muru's `printf` solution:

```
compgen -P "foo " -S " bar" -W "${array[*]}"
```

(note `-W` takes only a single option, so the array is flattened, and this causes problems with values with spaces or anything in `IFS`)

Comment:  Related: [Does bash support back references in parameter expansion?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/361134)

Comment: (though I don't really see how the `printf` command is clearer than `newarray[ii]="foo ${array[ii]} bar"`)

Comment: Just to separate out prefix/suffix/value from the line noise ;-)

Comment: Note that `printf -v array` does work in `zsh`. I've added that to my answer.