# Prepending some text to each element of an array

Tags: zsh

In `zsh`, with glob expansion we can use the `P` flag to prepend each match with some text:

```
$ ls -1
bar
baz
foo
$ print -- *(P:--file:)
--file bar --file baz --file foo
```

Is there something analogous for array parameters? If I write

```
items=(foo bar baz)
```

is there some flag I can use to get behavior like this?

```
$ print -- ${(...)items}
--file foo --file bar --file baz
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205274/22142

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best answer depends on what you need the modified array for.

1. If you’re generating command-line arguments (as in the question), *and* you’re using a tool that accepts flags like `--file=foo` as an alternative to `--file foo`, the most idiomatic approach is to use the `${^name}` form of expansion:

   ```
   $ items=(foo "two words" baz)
   $ print -lr -- --file=${^items}
   --file=foo
   --file=two words
   --file=baz
   ```

   I’m using `print -lr` to demonstrate that the expansion produces an array with three elements. If you call a command like this, the command will see three arguments.
2. If you’re generating command-line arguments, you can put the text to prepend (`--file` in this example) in a dummy array and combine that with the arguments array using the `${name:^^arrayname}` form of expansion:

   ```
   $ flag=(--file)
   $ items=(foo "two words" baz)
   $ print -lr -- ${flag:^^items}
   --file
   foo
   --file
   two words
   --file
   baz
   ```

   This is an array with six elements. Either this format or the one in (1)—or both—should be acceptable to just about any command-line tool for passing flags with associated values.
3. You can modify the approach in (1) to use a space instead of an equals sign:

   ```
   $ items=(foo "two words" baz)
   $ print -lr -- --file\ ${^items}
   --file foo
   --file two words
   --file baz
   ```

   (Note that you *have* to escape the space with a backslash; using double quotes like `"--file ${^items}"` means something else.) This is an array with three elements but with an embedded space in each element. Few, if any, command line tools will accept flags in this format, but it could be useful for other kinds of text manipulation.
4. You can also use the `${name/pattern/repl}` form of expansion. The pattern should start with `#` (to indicate that it needs to match at the beginning of each array element) but it should otherwise be empty (so that every array element will match and so that no text is actually replaced).

   ```
   $ items=(foo "two words" baz)
   $ print -lr -- ${items/#/--file }
   --file foo
   --file two words
   --file baz
   ```

   This has the same caveats as (3), and it’s also less idiomatic than that approach.

Note that all four of these approaches will do the right thing (i.e., they won’t suddenly split strings on spaces) when the array elements contain spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That’s good to know, thank you. And you made me realize that the “embedded space” problem I mentioned is irrelevant as long as the command accepts `--flag=value` as an alternative to `--flag value`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I’ve rewritten the answer based partially on your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `P` glob modifier! Everything can be a glob if you insist. Note that I'm not saying that I'd really *want* to do this. I can't think of a situation where it's the best way. But it is technically possible.

```
% items=(foo bar baz)
% print -lr -- /(P:--file:e\''reply=($items[@])'\')
--file
bar
--file
baz
--file
foo
```

It works by making a glob that matches exactly one file name (`/` will do nicely), using the glob qualifier `e` to replace the one match by an arbitrary list, and applying the `P` qualifier to the result.

This only works in contexts where globbing is performed, but that's usually a case where an array is allowed.

Comment: This is a fascinating abuse of glob modifiers  Thanks for demonstrating it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this portably (or, at least, portably to shells that support this array syntax) with `printf`:

```
$ items=(foo bar baz)
$ printf -- "--file %s " "${items[@]}"
--file foo --file bar --file baz $
```

Unlike the `print` command, however, that doesn't add a trailing newline (which is why you have the `$` on the same line as the output, above). If that's a deal breaker, you can do:

```
$ printf -- "--file %s " "${items[@]}"; echo ""
--file foo --file bar --file baz
```

Comment: There is no need for `echo ""`. A simpler `echo` is good enough.